# Vue.js best practice to remove component

Tags: vue.js

My website overwrites a specific DOM instead of asking for a page load. Sometimes, inside the DOM there will be some Vue.js components (all are single page components), which will be overwritten. Most of them reside in an app created for the sole purpose of building the component.

Two questions:

1. do I need to destroy those components? If YES: how?
2. Is there any better solution to this approach?

Answer (score 10):

There is a destroy command to erase components:

> Completely destroy a vm. Clean up its connections with other existing vms, unbind all its directives, turn off all event listeners.
> Triggers the beforeDestroy and destroyed hooks.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-destroy

But if you only want the remove/hide the components, which are inside of one or many instances (i.e. the ones that are mounted via `.$mount()` or `el: "#app"` ) you should try to remove the components via `v-if` or hide via `v-show`.

In the instance template this will look like:

```
<my-component v-if="showMyComponent"></my-component>
<my-component v-show="showMyComponent"></my-component>
```

The v-show will just set `display:none` while `v-if` will remove the component from the DOM in the same way as `$destroy()` does. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Doing this assumes that you keep track of what you have on your page and load everything at the beginning, while I use ajax to send <my-component></...>. I'm more interested in memory usage

Comment: If you use `v-if="x"`and x is a variable in your vm.data that is initialized with something that equals false, the component will not be loaded or rendered at the beginning. It will only then be loaded when x equals true.

Comment: When I change the value of "x" multiple times, the needed memory goes higher and higher. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Hillcow your saying that your creating and destroying a component multiple times right? In this case there are many possibilities, please keep in mind that there might be some data that is created or downloaded in your component and not fast forwarded to garbage collection. If you have some data in the component please use the `destroyed` lifecycle hook to clean up manualy with `destroy YOUR_OBJECTS`. That will prevent huge memory allocation.

Comment: Okay this is what I am wondering about. What kind of data could that be? Anything that I create purely in Vue without any external libraries or plugins shouldn’t be a problem, right? After opening and closing said component 20 times I go from around 25 to 50mb memory usage with the site.

Comment: Thats a js thing, not directly a vue thing. The garbage collection depens on your browser.

Comment: Nice and easy way!

Answer (score 3):

You must use a local data prop and use in in directives v-show and v-if

```
<div id="application">
    <vm-test v-if="active"></vm-test>
    <div @click="toggle()">toggle</div>
</div>

Vue.component('vm-test', {
    template: '<div>test</div>'
});

var vm = new Vue ({
    el: "#application",
    data: function() {
        return {
            active:true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggle: function() {
            this.active = !this.active;
        }
    }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/99yxdacy/2/

Comment: is this an answer for part #2?

Comment: look, if u wanna remove/hide component from Vue app you must use data property of Vue. If you wanna destroy Vue - use method $destroy.

i update my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/99yxdacy/3/

when you press "toggle" - you toggle component in DOM, when you press "destroy" - you remove Vue app from DOM.

Answer (score 0):

`v-if` can be used for this purpose. but if you are playing with parent child components, then it can be a bit tricky.

So, when your parent load, hide your child using `v-if` and pass the `props` to show or hide the child component.

`In my parent component`: hideStudentSection is passed as `props`. and one event named `navToParent` passed. `navToParent` will be used to reset the props when call comes back from child component.

```js
  <div class="container-fluid" v-if="nav.students">
    <div class="row">
        <students
          @navToParent="navToParent"
          :hideStudentSection="nav.hideStudentSection"
        />
    </div>
    <div @click="navToChild"> </div>
  </div>
export default defineComponent({
...
method() {
   navToChild() {
      this.nav.hideStudentSection = false;
      this.nav.students = true;
   },
   navToParent() {
      this.nav.hideStudentSection = true;
      this.nav.students = false;      
   }
}
})
```

`In my child component`: (note: I am showing only the relevant code). you can use mounted to handle your stuff

```js
<template>
  <div class="col-12" v-if="!hideStudentSection">
  </div>
<div @click="back">back to Parent</div>
</template>

export default defineComponent({
...
...
props: ["hideStudentSection"],
emits: ["navToParent"],
mounted() { 
  // use mounted to handle your stuff
},
methods: {
    back() {
      this.$emit("navToParent");
    },
}
});
```